# why is my for-each loop not working properly in parallel stages in jenkins scripted syntax?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Consider the following code:

```
List<String> strs = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']

Map parallelStages = [:]
for (s in strs) {
    String stageName = "print $s"
    parallelStages[stageName] = {
        stage(stageName) {
           println "Hello, $s"
        }
    }
    
}
parallel parallelStages
```

The output of this is

```
Hello, baz
Hello, baz
Hello, baz
```

Whereas I would have expected:

```
Hello, foo
Hello, bar
Hello, baz
```

This snippet works properly if I comment out the lines containing "parallel".

For the record, if I print out the content of `parallelStages` Map, I get `{print foo=org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@38d330f7, print bar=org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@30e6a23b, print baz=org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@6abe446}`

Environment info:

Jenkins: 2.332.2

Pipeline plugin: 2.7

Update: I could reproduce the same(?) problem in core groovy with Closures. Posted that one as a separate question:
[What's wrong with this groovy for-loop of Closures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899783/whats-wrong-with-this-groovy-for-loop-of-closures)

Comment: If your block scope reassigned variable `stageName` resolves correctly during concurrency, then why not use that instead of the lambda scope variable `s`?

Comment: @MattSchuchard The main point of my original code is that somehow the controller variable of the for loop is always the last one of the list and I don't know why. I think this is not related to concurrency issues. At least I could reproduce the same issue with plain closures in core groovy. See my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899783/whats-wrong-with-this-groovy-for-loop-of-closures